# Jquery does not work on server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

Currently I work in local mode with a Web application developed in .NET using c #, Html and JavaScript, which works perfectly (in local mode).

But, when I do the publication in the server of this Web App, the functionalities of it are lost, because the Jquery does not recognize it in the libraries Jquery UI, Data Tables and Bootstrap.js.

It is important to mention that the server where the IIS was installed to deploy the Web is inside an intranet and does not have free access to the internet; and that is why all the JS libraries mentioned above download them and included them in the same project so as not to be taking external references and avoid that type of problem (even if those scripts are executed on the client's side).

But still the project still does not work, and that's why I wonder, is it necessary for the server to have internet access to be able to execute those scripts even though they are included in the project?

```
<head id="myHeader" runat="server">
     <script type="text/javascript"  src='<%= ResolveUrl ("~/js/jquery-3.3.1.js") %>'></script>
     <script type="text/javascript"  src='<%= ResolveUrl ("~/js/jquery-ui.min.js") %>'></script>
     <script type="text/javascript"  src='<%= ResolveUrl ("~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js") %>'></script>
     <script type="text/javascript"  src='<%= ResolveUrl ("~/js/bootstrap.min.js") %>'></script>
     <script type="text/javascript"  src='<%= ResolveUrl ("~/js/underscore.js") %>'></script>
```

I have declared the scripts in this way on the website, if anyone has any idea what may be happening, I really appreciate the support.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you verified that it is pulling in jquery correctly?

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct path to your jQuery file? It looks like your other JS files are all .min.js (minified) but your main jQuery reference doesn't have .min in the filename. A screenshot of your Network tab open after a page reload would help.

Comment: check via the Network tab in your browser (when the page loads) that the jQuery file is loading correctly (i.e. returns a 200 OK response for that JS file). If not, check that the file is present on your server and is in the correct location being referenced by your page (you can see the path it's trying to find it in in the Network tab as well)

Comment: I have add the screenshot from Network Tab

Comment: I have checked on the server and the JS file structure is identical to the one I have in local mode.

Comment: you're not loading jquery twice or anything silly like that?

Comment: P.S. "that is why all the JS libraries mentioned above download them and included them in the same project so as not to be taking external references and avoid that type of problem" makes no sense. When you include a file via a `<link` or `<script` reference in the HTML, it's the _browser_ which makes the request direct to the URL in that link. Your webserver is not involved, unless it's the target of the URL. That's one reason why CDNs are so popular - it reduces bandwidth usage from your server by making the page fetch the resources from elsewhere.

Comment: So, Should I take the scripts by external references?

Comment: It's up to you. Doesn't really matter to this issue, so long as they load correctly, in the right order, and before any other code tries to use them, and the versions are all compatible with each other and with the code on the page.

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-is-jquery-undefined--cms-24406